Error "Version increment needed to allow dexie-cloud change tracking" with dexie-cloud add-on
I'm trying to add the dexie-cloud add-on to my local Dexie database. It works fine if there's no pre-existing dexie data in the browser. However, if I try to run the app in a browser where previous data exists (with nameSuffix: false), dexie stops working and gives me the following error:

DexieError {name: 'DatabaseClosedError', message: 'SchemaError Version increment needed to allow dexie-cloud change tracking', inner: DexieError}

However, even if I do what specified and increase the database version, nothing changes. Furthermore, I can see from the broser DevTools that the db version is not changed.
Any tip in terms of how to further debug this and fix it?

This sounds like dexie@3 is being used. Dexie Cloud requires dexie@4 (latest). Can you confirm this was the case?

no that is not the issue... I have 4.0.1 for both dexie and dexie-cloud-addon

Ok. Are you declaring the database using db.version(x).stores({...}) or are you opening it dynamically (without ever setting db.version(x).stores({...})? Dexie Cloud needs you to keep specifying version().stores() to have a chance to add its own tables. If you do have a static schema, what happens if you increment the version number? (using (db.version(2).stores({...}) instead of db.version(1).stores({...}) ?

Thanks for your help!
I do declare it before - I use Typescript, so I create a custom class that extends Dexie, then create an instance of the class.
If I increment the version of the schema: it works fine without the dexie-cloud addon, but with it (and with nameSuffix: false), I get presented the error above and the schema upgrade never happens.
(with nameSuffix: true Dexie creates a new instance of the database, so the above issue doesn't happen, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve.)

Tried to reproduce it but I don't get any error when using nameSuffix: false, so I suppose it's tied to the state of your current database somehow. If the database have come into a bad state, you could clear the sync state: Go to devtools --> applications --> IndexedDB and open your database. Click table $syncState and delete all rows there. Also delete any row in $logins table. Then refresh your application to it can start over.

The thing is, there is no $syncState nor $login to my current database, since it's a local database that was previously created with local dexie - before I added the dexie-cloud addon. I don't have a reason to think my db is a bad state, since everything works smoothly without dexie-cloud. If I remove it entirely and let dexie-cloud create one from scratch then everything works fine, but this is not a real solution to the problem...
Any other possible culprit? I have a custom auth flow (with firebase)... Could that impact it?
